# Is it possible to add second horizontal Menu below Main Menu?

Tags: routes

- I use "user menu" on top, for user related links.
- I use "main menu", in reaching my main contents of site.

I need one more horizontal menu below the "main menu".
So second priority links will be there.
Can it be possible?

(I'm not interested with drop down menus. "Main Menu" and "Second Horizontal Menu" will be independent of each other)

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to /admin/structure/menu/add and add a new menu
2. Go to /admin/structure/block and place the new menu block in the region of your choosing.

Comment: That way doesn't give a horizontal menu.   It gives an unordered list of links, vertically. I need a horizontal menu under the main menu.

Comment: Your going to have to add some css to display them inline. e.g. .YOUR_MENU_NAME li {display: inline;}